# Make currentText Button Close Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the currentText button close the datepicker popup when clicked. Right now I'm trying

```js
$('body').on('click', '.ui-datepicker-current', function() {
  
  $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
});
```

But it's not alerting or anything. I'm not sure how to select it. I used another normal button to test it and it did close the datepicker.

Comment: So you want to alert when date is clicked?

Comment: The alert was just for testing. I just need it to hide the datepicker

Comment: can you add html as well?

Comment: What is _currentText button_ and why do you have to manually close the calendar popup?

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually using .datetimepicker and currentText (https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-currentText) is an option to set a button to get the Current time and date. It's built in but I'm wanting it to close the whole box on clicking it.

Comment: I just inspected it to find the ui-datepicker-current class

Answer (score 1):

It appears that jquery UI is preventing the propagation of the click event on the "Today" button. What you could do is have a click event on the container div and check if the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the button.

e.g.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  showButtonPanel: true
});

$('.ui-datepicker').click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("ui-datepicker-current")) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("hide");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The click event handler can be bound to any div as below

`$( "#target" ).click(function() 
{` 
`alert( "Handler for .click() called." )});`

In your case you would like the date-picker div to close upon clicking the current text button? and im guessing the class selector for the current-text-button is .ui-datepicker-current? so im guessing here without seeing your code:

`$('.ui-datepicker-current').click(function(){`
   `$('##ui-datepicker-div').hide(); })`

hope this helps :)

sorry for the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, this will work:

```
$('#currentTextId').on('click', function() {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
});
```